# Llenar textbox con combobox

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, wpf, xaml

Estoy tratando de llenar unos `TextBox` a partir de un dato del `ComboBox`, mi problema esta en que muestro los datos del `ComboBox` y se llenan los `TextBox` pero cuando cambio de item en el `ComboBox` los datos del `TextBox` se quedan estáticos.

Comparto el código.

**C#:**

```
/*PROCEDIMIENTO PARA CARGAR LOS PRODUCTOS CON SU CODIGO PSL Y TOTALIZADOR*/
        private void ListarProductos()
        {
            using(DB_SICAPEntities entidades = new DB_SICAPEntities())
            {
                var query = from i in entidades.tblItems
                            join t in entidades.tblItemsTotalizador
                            on i.idTotalizador equals t.id
                            where i.Activo == true
                            select new
                            {
                                i.Item,
                                i.CodigoPSL,
                                t.CodigoTotalizador
                            };

                foreach(var result in query)
                {
                    productos.Add(new tblItems { Item = result.Item, CodigoPSL = result.CodigoPSL });
                    txtTotalizador.Text = result.CodigoTotalizador;
                    txtPsl.Text = Convert.ToString(result.CodigoPSL);
                }
                productos.Add(new tblItems { id = int.Parse("-1"), Item = "Productos" });
                this.cmbProductos.DisplayMemberPath = "Item";
                this.cmbProductos.SelectedValuePath = "id";
                this.cmbProductos.ItemsSource = productos.OrderBy(P => (P.id)).ToList();
                this.cmbProductos.SelectedValue = "-1";
            }

        }
```

**XAML:**

```
<Label Content="Seleccionar Producto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.132,4.423" Width="133" FontSize="12" Foreground="#FF5B5B5B" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbProductos" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,82,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="198" Height="23"/>
        <Label Content="Código PSL" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="271,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.132,4.423" Width="133" FontSize="12" Foreground="#FF5B5B5B" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtPsl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Cursor="Help" Height="23" Margin="271,82,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="186" ToolTip="No puedes modificar este campo" Foreground="White" Background="Gray"/>
        <Label Content="Código Totalizador" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.132,4.423" Width="133" FontSize="12" Foreground="#FF5B5B5B" FontWeight="SemiBold" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtTotalizador" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Cursor="Help" Height="23" Margin="39,82,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="186" Grid.Column="1" ToolTip="No puedes modificar este campo" Foreground="White" Background="Gray"/>
```

De ante mano muchas gracias por sus aportes.

Comment: @gbianchi Hola, estoy tratando con este evento SelectionChanged="cmbProductos_SelectionChanged" pero casi no encuentro documentacion de como trabajarlo con entity

Comment: @gbianchi Es que es allí donde estoy como confundido, estoy tratando de mostrar en el textbox este txtTotalizador y este txtPsl que los valores los traigo con un Join echo en linq, entonces no se como pasar ese valor a los textbox cuando cambio el selectedValue

Comment: @gbianchi también trate como me lo explicas pero no me arroja información, me podrias regalar un ejemplo a nivel de codigo, para comparar en que estoy fallando?

Comment: @gbianchi si es correcto traer otro valor segun la elección del combo

Comment: Entonces para eso a tu pregunta le falta el modelo EF del cual queres traer el valor. No soy experto en EF, pero no deja de ser igual a lo que venis haciendo. solo que vas a tener como parametro la seleccion del combo.

Comment: @gbianchi Segun lo que dices debo armar la consulta en el SelectionChanged y pasarle como parametro el valor que obtiene del combo?

Comment: deberia ser algo asi como lo que decis...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que recomendaria es que no necesitas realizar un foreach para convertir objeto de linq, puedes hacer todo en la misma accion

```
public class Item
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Item {get;set;}
   public string CodigoPSL {get;set;}
   public string CodigoTotalizador {get;set;}
}

private void ListarProductos()
{
    using(DB_SICAPEntities entidades = new DB_SICAPEntities())
    {
        var query = (from i in entidades.tblItems
                    join t in entidades.tblItemsTotalizador on i.idTotalizador equals t.id
                    where i.Activo == true
                    orderby i.id
                    select new Item()
                    {
                        Id = i.id,
                        Item = i.Item,
                        CodigoPSL = i.CodigoPSL,
                        CodigoTotalizador = t.CodigoTotalizador
                    }).ToList();


        query.Insert(0, new tblItems { Id= -1, Item = "Productos" });

        this.cmbProductos.DisplayMemberPath = "Item";
        this.cmbProductos.SelectedValuePath = "id";
        this.cmbProductos.ItemsSource = query;
        this.cmbProductos.SelectedValue = "-1";
    }

}
```

veras en el `select` como se define la clase que quiers obtener y ademas aplicar orden y filtro todo en uno

Despues en el xaml debes asignar el evento `SelectionChanged`

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbProductos" SelectionChanged="cmbProductos_SelectionChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,82,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="198" Height="23"/>
```

Para poder tener el item seleccionado y cargar los textbox

```
private void cmbProductos_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;

    var item = comboBox.SelectedItem as tblItems;

    txtTotalizador.Text = item.CodigoTotalizador;
    txtPsl.Text = item.CodigoPSL;
}
```

puedes obtener la clase asignada como datasource y tomar las propiedades.
Valida las propiedades de la clase `tblItems`

Comment: Intente con tu ejemplo pero me arroja el siguiente error, **System.NotSupportedException: 'No es posible construir la entidad o el tipo complejo 'DB_SICAPModel.tblItems' en una consulta LINQ to Entities.**

Comment: estas usando entity framework ?

Comment: Si uso entity framework

Comment: una duda, la clase tblItems, es la misma que estas mapeando con EF ? porque si es asi deberias crear una nueva clase para usar en el select del linq

Comment: Si es la misma del EF, como deberia crear una nueva?

Comment: sabes definir una class ? solo cras una nueva para usar en el select con las propiedades que quieras utilizar

Comment: edite el ejemplo definiendo una class nueva

Comment: Con ambos ejemplos me funciono correctamente, el error se estaba generando porque una de las propiedades la declaramos como string y en la db estaba numeric. Muchas gracias por tu apoyo